# Error correction codes for correcting 4 error bits

Tags: error-correction

I have a string message "Man" where each character is encoded to 8 bits. Therefore, a total of 24 bits will be transmitted.

I am very interested to know what are the error correction codes that are not able to correct more than 4 error bits. More specifically, is there any error correction that can correct at most 4 errors ?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: one easy way of error correction is BINARY Search method by checking parities.why you want to correct only 4 errors?

Comment: Yes I am interested to use a non efficient error correction. Do you know any code that can correct only 4 bits ?

Comment: Why is this tagged `image-processing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have corrupt string A=[ 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0]; and original string B=[1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1].

step 1: check the parity of A and B: that are 1 and 0.

step 2: parity is unmatched, so divide the string A and B by half and check the parity  in first half. if parity is matched on first half leave that half and take the 2nd half, where there must be unmatched parity. For our case first half parity has not matched now leave the 2nd half. Take the first half and again apply divide and conquer method until you end up with 1 bit. Now you detect the error bit. so flip the error bit in A (i.e correct).

step 3: permute the bitstrings A and B with same permutation function so that error locations are changed. now do again from step 1.

repeat the procedure , until your desired error correction numbers.

Comment: What is the name of this error correction code? are you sure about this explanation ?

Comment: this is the good way to do, try this. it works, you can correct more than 20% erros if you want.

Comment: Thank you, really it is a very interesting method